# UWSGI block incoming connections when all threads are busy

Tags: uwsgi

I have a simple UWSGI app put behind a LB with the following .ini config

```
[uwsgi]
socket=0.0.0.0:5071
chdir = src/
wsgi-file = uwsgi.py
processes=2
threads=1
protocol=http
plugins=python
exit-on-reload=false
master=true
# Cleanup of temp files
vacuum = true
```

When all `2x1` threads are busy, the application **keeps serving** incoming connections by queueing them, waiting for a thread to free.

This is somehow an unwanted behavior in my case, as I would like UWSGI to return a 5xx status code which will allow me to not oversaturate the resources of a single distribution.

**Client testing code**

Attaching the test client code for the UWSGI application

```
proxy = {
    'http':'http://localhost:5071'
}

@threaded
def f():
    print('Sending request')
    response = requests.get('http://dummy.site',proxies=proxy)
    print(str(response.status_code )+ response.text)

for i in range(5):
    f()
```

**Test (1)**

Adding `listen = 2` to .ini and firing 3 requests simultaneously would just print:

`*** uWSGI listen queue of socket "0.0.0.0:5071" (fd: 3) full !!! (3/2) ***`

while the third connection seems to still be somehow accepted, queued and later executed instead of a `5xx` error being thrown.

**Test (2)**

Adding `listen = 0` to .ini and firing 5 requests simultaneously would just execute two requests at a time. The full queue output is not showing anymore. Somehow, the requests are somewhere still queued and executed when threads get freed.

How can I block incoming connections to the UWSGI application when all threads are busy?

Comment: Your configuration has a different port and listen queue than the logged message. Are you running two instances and checking a different than you meant to? Also, *almost* every use case works better with (at least some small) listen backlog - when done do check if your performance metrics really match up with your expectations.

Comment: @anx just a mistake as I switched ports while writing the question. Regarding the backlogging, which option(s) do you particularly refer to?

Comment: Is the client you are using to test this maybe **retrying** *after* uwsgi turns down the connection attempt once? Maybe your configuration worked, but your test method did not?

Comment: @anx It is not retrying at all, using simple `requests.get(url,proxies)` in python

Answer (score 0):

This is a truly bizarre request, but if you really want to do this, you can try reducing the [listen queue](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html#the-listen-queue) (to zero), i.e. `--listen 0`. I haven't tested this and don't know if zero is even considered a valid value. This is something that is normally *increased* as a site gains traffic, not decreased.

Comment: With `listen = 0` all that happens is that the output of the queue being full does not show anymore. It still seems that "somewhere" it is hanging until the threads are freed. I have attached my testing client in the question. Thank you!

Comment: @Constantin It might be that this is just not possible. I could not find anybody else who even tried to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is actually weird - I am wondering why shouldn't a web server have the ability to be limited on connections amount. Especially when these applications are put behind a whole infrastructure meant to work with load balancers, auto scaling groups and calculated pre-allocated resources